# Error in importing a file in Python 3.3.6

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to learn the Stackless python and I got the latest 3.3.6. I created a try.py file and wrote the content

```
print " Hello world"
print " Good evening"
```

Then in the python command prompt, gave the command

```
import try.py
```

It gave the error , 
Syntax error: invalid syntax as shown in the figure below:[image]

What's wrong here? I have placed the file in C:\Python33.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because [`try`](http://zetcode.com/lang/python/keywords/) is a reserved keyword in python.
Try again after renaming your file to something else.
Also, during importing, specifying the extension of the python file is wrong.
Instead of `import mymodule.py`, you should simply write `import mymodule`.